# multiple return statements at once?

Tags: php, return, chatbot

I am trying to develop a chat bot.

I have a doubt regarding the functionality.

**Here's a part of the code:**

```
<?php
require_once 'bootstrap.php';
require_once CB_HOME.'/library/CommonFunctions.php';

class testBot extends AbstractCbRest{
  public function subscriptionCreated($userName){
    return "Welcome ";
  } 
  public function subscriptionDeleted($userName){
    return "Thanks  ";
  }
  public function messageReceived($from, $message){
    return "" ; // how to return multiple  here
  }
```

In the messageReceived function ,I am going to implement the chatbot functionality.

Whenever i get a message from the user i am going to return something.For that i will have to run some php scripts and make some api calls.The final result i will send to the user.

All this is going to take approximately 20-25 seconds.

Is there a way I can send multiple return statements?
Like while the Api calls are being made i can send a message to the user and then wait for the actual result to come and then send it?
I cannot think of a way because as soon i sent a message,i cannot return something until and unless user replies with something.

Answer (score 4):

Use an array :

```
public function messageReceived($from, $message){
    return array(
        'Welcome',
        'Thanks',
        'Hello',
        'Whatever'
    );
}
```

Or even an associative array

```
array(
    'msg1' => 'Welcome',
    'msg2' => 'Thanks',
    'msg3' => 'Hello',
    'msg4' => 'Whathever'
)
```

Then you can use a particular message with :

```
array['msg1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array and return that :

```
public function messageReceived($from, $message){
  $retval = array();
  $retval[] = "message1";
  $retval[] = "message2";
  return $retval;
}
```

or

```
public function messageReceived($from, $message){
  return array("message1","message2");
}
```

Comment: message2 in this case should be the response i am getting from the api calls?

Comment: @Shiven it can be anything you want it to be - a boolean / number / string etc

Comment: One doubt ,lets say $message1="please wait while loading"
and $message2=$response

when i return the array,there would be time before response getts stored in message2, will it return $message1 and then after sometime return $message2

Comment: @Shiven so you want to display a message to the user while the function executes - not return multiple values from the function .... use JavaScript to display the message and PHP to return the result

Comment: yeah exactly,i want to send something to the user while the actual data to be send is processed? there is no method for that in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to think about using AJAX rather than making synchronous calls while the page rendering is being processed.

Comment: i am not familiar with ajax ! is there a way to handle this in PHP?

Comment: You'll probably want to check out something like jQuery. This lets you easily issue AJAX calls and handle the asynchronous return value(s). Create a PHP page to handle the AJAX call e.g. the JS uses $.ajax("postmessage.php") which eventually returns "message posted". While the AJAX call is running, your client is still free to navigate around your page. You may need to do some googling as I can't easily do the topic justice in a few hundred characters